# How can I improve this algorithm to count the frequency of characters in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array

In order to sort in a descending manner, the frequency of char appearance in a string, I've developed the following algorithm.

First I pass the string to a dictionary using each char as a key along with its frequency of appearance as value. Afterwards I have converted the dictionary to a descending sorted multi-dimension list.

I'd like to know how to improve the algorithm, was it a good approach? Can it be done diferently? All proposals are welcome.

```
#Libraries
from operator import itemgetter
# START

# Function
# String to Dict. Value as freq. 
# of appearance and char as key.
def frequencyChar(string):
    #string = string.lower() # Optional
    freq = 0
    thisDict = {}
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha(): # just chars
            freq = string.count(char)
            thisDict[char] = freq # {key:value}
    return(thisDict)

str2Dict = frequencyChar("Would you like to travel with me?")
#print(str2Dict)
# Dictionary to list
list_key_value = [[k,v] for k, v in str2Dict.items()]
# Descending sorted list
list_key_value = sorted(list_key_value, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print("\n", list_key_value, "\n")

#END
```

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [codereview.se]. If you don't get a good answer here, you might want to try there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing *way* too much work. `collections.Counter` counts things for you automatically, and even sorts by frequency:

```
from collections import Counter
s = "Would you like to travel with me?"
freq = Counter(s)
# Counter({' ': 6, 'o': 3, 'l': 3, 'e': 3, 't': 3, 'u': 2, 'i': 2, 'W': 1, 'd': 1, 'y': 1, 'k': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'v': 1, 'w': 1, 'h': 1, 'm': 1, '?': 1})
```

If you want to remove the spaces from the count:

```
del freq[' ']
# Counter({'o': 3, 'l': 3, 'e': 3, 't': 3, 'u': 2, 'i': 2, 'W': 1, 'd': 1, 'y': 1, 'k': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'v': 1, 'w': 1, 'h': 1, 'm': 1, '?': 1})
```

Also just in general, your algorithm is doing too much work. `string.count` involves iterating over the whole string for each character you're trying to count. Instead, you can just iterate *once* over the whole string, and for every letter you just keep incrementing the key associated with that letter (initialize it to 1 if it's a letter you haven't seen before). That's essentially what `Counter` is doing for you.

Spelling it out:

```
count = {}
for letter in the_string:
    if not letter.isalpha():
        continue
    if letter not in count:
        count[letter] = 1
    else:
        count[letter] += 1
```

And then to sort it you don't need to convert to a list first, you can just do it directly:

```
ordered = sorted(count.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely Counter() is the way to go. With your example and @Eli Korvigo's I see my error when running thru string twice, hence O(n^2).

Comment: "... and even sorts by frequency" – this is not actually the case, you need to call `Counter.most_common` to get frequency-sorted output.